# Memory error when using BioPython to read FASTA alignment

Tags: python, cluster-computing, biopython

I am using BioPython to read in an alignment of 120 sequences (approx. 20kb each) on the computing cluster at my workplace. My code works perfectly on my own computer (Mac OSX Mavericks, runs in <1 sec) and also works when I use Python interactively on the cluster. However, when I try to run a longer program containing my code (below), I run into a MemoryError.

```
from Bio import AlignIO
alignment = AlignIO.read("my_aligment.fasta","fasta")
```

The traceback looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./my_program.py", line 42, in <module>
    alignment = AlignIO.read(align, "fasta")
  File "/workplace/software/free/Linux/redhat_5_x86_64/pkgs/python_2.7.1-sqlite3-rtrees/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/AlignIO/__init__.py", line 423, in read
    first = next(iterator)
  File "/workplace/software/free/Linux/redhat_5_x86_64/pkgs/python_2.7.1-sqlite3-rtrees/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/AlignIO/__init__.py", line 370, in parse
    for a in i:
  File "/workplace/software/free/Linux/redhat_5_x86_64/pkgs/python_2.7.1-sqlite3-rtrees/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/AlignIO/__init__.py", line 270, in _SeqIO_to_alignment_iterator
    records = list(SeqIO.parse(handle, format, alphabet))
  File "/workplace/software/free/Linux/redhat_5_x86_64/pkgs/python_2.7.1-sqlite3-rtrees/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 586, in parse
    for r in i:
  File "/workplace/software/free/Linux/redhat_5_x86_64/pkgs/python_2.7.1-sqlite3-rtrees/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/FastaIO.py", line 121, in FastaIterator
    for title, sequence in SimpleFastaParser(handle):
  File "/workplace/software/free/Linux/redhat_5_x86_64/pkgs/python_2.7.1-sqlite3-rtrees/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/FastaIO.py", line 55, in SimpleFastaParser
    line = handle.readline()
MemoryError
```

Perhaps I am running into a memory error on the server, but I thought the whole point of using AlignIO was that it is very efficient memory-wise. And I'm confused because I can run that line of code successfully on the cluster when I use Python interactively.

Other relevant information:
Python version 2.7.1,
Biopython version 1.64

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Comment: What is the file size? What does your RAM look like on the local machine?

Comment: Also, which version of python are you using? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: File is 2.4 MB. Local machine RAM is 4GB. How do I check if python is 32 or 64 bit? Thanks!

Comment: It will show at the top of the python interpreter. You can either open up IDLE or just enter python into the command line.

Comment: That being said, 2.4 MB is relatively small.If you can run this with 4GB RAM it shouldn't be all that computationally intensive.

Comment: I'm using 64 bit python. But I agree, it shouldn't be that computationally intensive (hence running on my personal machine just fine) so I'm confused as to why it cannot run while I'm hooked up to the company server.

Comment: When you submit the job to the cluster, do you specify the memory allocation?

ie for slurm:

`#sbatch --mem 1000`